# Is there an easier way to do this query in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql

As an example, I have the below table which contains user review of products

```
       tblreviews
ID  |   product  | review|

==========================

1   | pen        |   2   |

2   | pen        |   2   |

3   | ink        |   1   |

4   | ink        |   1   |
```

I would like to write a query that will add up the values for each item and then give me the top 5, in this example I need to extract the data:

1. Product: Pen Average review: 2/5
2. Product: Ink Average review: 1/5

-

```
select sum (review) from tblreviews where product name= 'pen'
select count (pen) from tblreviews where product name= 'pen'
```

Then I can calculate the average review from the result of them, but I will have to do that with every product in the table, this will then give me a league table of products by the highest review, which is what I'm trying to get.

Is there an easier was of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top 5 products by average review:

```
SELECT product, AVG(review) AS Average_review
 FROM tblreviews
 GROUP BY product
 ORDER BY Average_review DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: tblProduct

¦prodID ¦Product¦
¦1 ¦pen ¦
¦2 ¦ink ¦

tblReview
¦RevID ¦prodID ¦Rating ¦
¦1 ¦1 ¦2 ¦
¦2 ¦1 ¦2 ¦
¦3 ¦2 ¦1 ¦
¦4 ¦2 ¦1 ¦

Im usind the following SQL query:

SELECT prodID, AVG(review) AS Average_review
 FROM tblReview
 GROUP BY product
 ORDER BY Average_review DESC
 LIMIT 5

Gives me:

1.productID: 1 Average Rating: 2
2.productID: 2 Average Rating: 1

What i'd actually like to display is:


1.product: Pen Average Rating: 2
2.product: Ink Average Rating: 1

Could anybody help, many thanks in advance

Comment: @JonathanReeks Use [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) for this. If you need more advice, please fill in a new question, not comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use group by

```
Select product, avg(review) as average
From tblreviews
Group by product
Order by average desc
Limit 5
```